# Programming a 2d enemy in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have been working on enemies in my game, but feel the code is clunky as is and also does not seem to work. I put code into my player script and enemy script. the player script is as follows:

EDIT: sorry for not being clear enough, here are the lines of code that do not work and what I want them to do:

```
 void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") 
    {
        Destroy (this.gameObject);
    }
    }
```

What i want in this code is for when the player encounters an enemy or object with the "Enemy" tag, touching that object will destroy or kill the player object.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Killable")
    {
        Debug.Log ("entering killzone!");
        Destroy (other.gameObject);
        Instantiate (DeadStar, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        this.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        }
    }
}
```

This code was loosely copied from a previous game, this has bits of it's killzone and was made to destroy the player object when it touches any object that contains this script. (the player is tagged "Killable")

hope this edit helps, im a little tired and forgot to specify things, sorry about that.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    public float JumpSpeed;
    public float Scale;
    public string JumpKey;
    public string LeftKey;
    public string RightKey;
    public float speed;
    public GameObject Player;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") 
    {
        Destroy (this.gameObject);
    }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().freezeRotation = true;       /*GetComponent<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;*/
    rb = GetComponent (typeof(Rigidbody2D)) as Rigidbody2D;
}
void FixedUpdate () 
{
    Vector3 hold = rb.velocity;
    hold.x = 0;
    if (Input.GetKey (LeftKey))
    {
        hold.x -= speed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (RightKey)) 
    {
        hold.x += speed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space))
    {
        hold.y = JumpSpeed; 
    } 
    rb.velocity = hold;
}
```

}

The enemy script is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyKillzone : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject DeadStar;
public GameObject Player;


void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Killable")
    {
        Debug.Log ("entering killzone!");
        Destroy (other.gameObject);
        Instantiate (DeadStar, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        this.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe your question will be re-opened shortly. In the meantime, I'd like to recommend you to *when you have your code working*, to post on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). I think you will be able to learn quite a bit from that site, and that you would fit in well there.

Comment: In the GameObject of PlayerController, Do you have a Collider with the field "isTrigger" activated?

Comment: what a surprise, no answers... anyway. You show the code that doesn't work, but you do not explain what it is currently doing that is wrong. Does the code even run? What is the `Destroy` function as I don't see it defined anywhere. Maybe `Destroy` is a function of the framework, which I am not familiar with, but if this is the case then this is the exact reason why I recommended [gamedev.se] before, because people over there will have a lot more specialist knowledge with the framework than us 'general programming' SO users. If you don't want to move site, then explain the problem better here

Comment: ok, so after some research, `Destroy` is a framework function. So what you really need to work out is: does `OnTriggerEnter2D` even get called? (add a breakpoint). If it does, what are the values of `other` and `tag`, are they what you expect? Another thing, are you sure `this` is the right thing you want to destroy? Could be a lack of my unity knowledge, but I am not convinced that it the actual "player" object. I mean, what is `Player` then? Just an inexperienced guess, but how about trying `Destroy(Player);` instead?

Comment: The code seems fine to me. Probably the method `OnTriggerEnter2D` is not getting called or the collider `other` doesn't have an `enemy` tag. `OnTriggerEnter2D` is called by the Unity3D physics, thats why I asked about the GameObject collider configuration.

Comment: @RicardoReiter: Yeah I suspected it to be a config issue of some kind, that's why I asked if OP was sure the event was being called. Which is also why I voted to close as I don't think it can be confidently answered until more information is provided. OP doesn't seem too bothered about it though so